# Custom cursor image change on position not working with safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I did a custom css cursor image change depending on the image position.
It is working with Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

Safari shows only the first state (cursor image.) How can I make the switch work with Safari?

```
$('body').on('mousemove', '.content img', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    if (x > $(this).width() / 2) {
      console.log("right");
        $('.content img').css({
            "cursor": "url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2216.899px%22%20height%3D%2215.799px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016.899%2015.799%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2016.899%2015.799%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E.weiss%20%7Bfill%3A%23ffffff%3B%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cg%3E%20%3Cg%3E%20%20%3Crect%20class%3D%22weiss%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%226.4%22%20width%3D%2215%22%20height%3D%222.999%22%2F%3E%20%3C%2Fg%3E%20%3Cpolygon%20class%3D%22weiss%22%20points%3D%229%2C0%207%2C2%2012.899%2C7.9%207%2C13.799%209%2C15.799%2016.899%2C7.9%20%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') 8 8,auto"
        });
    } else {
      console.log("left");
        $('.content img').css({
            "cursor": "url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2216.899px%22%20height%3D%2215.799px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016.899%2015.799%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2016.899%2015.799%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E.weiss%20%7Bfill%3A%23ffffff%3B%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cg%3E%20%3Cg%3E%20%20%3Crect%20class%3D%22weiss%22%20x%3D%222%22%20y%3D%226.4%22%20width%3D%2215%22%20height%3D%222.999%22%2F%3E%20%3C%2Fg%3E%20%3Cpolygon%20class%3D%22weiss%22%20points%3D%227.899%2C15.799%209.899%2C13.799%204%2C7.898%209.899%2C2%207.899%2C0%200%2C7.898%20%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') 8 8,auto"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add your code so others can help.

Comment: had first to figure out how to link to my fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/codedude/anstLfw7/

Comment: Is this not possible with Safari? (or Safari-Bug)